# How can I check the status periodically and syncronlicaly with a request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

**The context of the problem is the following:**

I do a petition to the back and this starts with a slow process that you can check with a rest request.

I need to continue with the main thread when this request indicates that the process is completed.

So I do a request to launch that process, after that, I want to make a request every 20 seconds in order to know if the process is finished and finally I want to continue with the main thread.

In order to solve this I triyed the following code:

```
 ...
 const checker = await setInterval(() => {
     let state = checkState(exportId)
      if(state !== '100%'){
        state = checkState(exportId)
      }else{
        clearInterval(checker)
        console.log('Clear interval')
      }
 }, 20000);
 ...
```

The check state function is the following:

```
checkState = async (exportId: string): Promise<IStatus> => {
    const headers = {...}
    const query = JSON.stringify({...});
    const { _, data } = await axios.post(...);
    return data
  };
```

The problem with this code is that when I execute it the code inside setInterval never is executed.

So how can I solve this, and await the `setInterval` until the state return `100%`?

Thanks

Comment: `checkState` is an async function. You'll have to `await` for it in the `setInterval`'s callback function.

Comment: setInterval is unaware of promises. The implementation depends on details you didn’t think of. What should happen if checkState takes more than 20s? Should there be simultaneous requests? Should it wait for existing one before spawning another? Should previous one be canceled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const checker = await setInterval(() => {
```

`setInterval` does not return a promise, it returns an identifier so you can later cancel the interval. Awaiting this value does nothing.

```
let state = checkState(exportId)
      if(state !== '100%'){
```

`checkState` is an async function which means it will always return a promise. It will never return a string. `await` the promise until it resolves to a string:

```
 const checker = setInterval(async () => {
     let state = await checkState(exportId);
      if(state !== '100%'){
        // no need to call checkState because you're using setInterval.
        // state = checkState(exportId)
        console.log('State currently is', state);
      }else{
        clearInterval(checker);
        console.log('Clear interval');
      }
 }, 20000);
```

Or equivalently:

```
 const checker = setInterval(() => {
     checkState(exportId).then((state) => {
      if(state !== '100%'){
        // no need to call checkState because you're using setInterval.
        // state = checkState(exportId)
        console.log('State currently is', state);
      }else{
        clearInterval(checker);
        console.log('Clear interval');
      }
     });
 }, 20000);
```

You could wrap the entire thing up in a promise to continue when the main process has finished:

```
const finished = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 const checker = setInterval(async () => {
     let state = await checkState(exportId);
      if(state !== '100%'){
        // no need to call checkState because you're using setInterval.
        // state = checkState(exportId)
        console.log('State currently is', state);
      }else{
        clearInterval(checker);
        resolve();
        console.log('Clear interval');
      }
 }, 20000);
});

await finished;

console.log("Done");
```